# Qual a diferença entre docker-compose e DockerFile?

Tags: docker

Qual a diferença entre docker-compose e DockerFile, especificamente?

1. O docker-compose usa o DockerFile ou vice-versa?
2. Consigo fazer toda configuração só com um deles? Se sim, qual?

Answer (score 7):

O proposito dos 2 é bem diferente. O dockerfile descreve uma IMAGEM de container que poderá ser usada posteriormente, inclusive em um docker-compose.

O docker-compose pode ser comparado aos orquestradores de containers. Nele é possível criar uma série de serviços e configurações.

Portanto, um não substitui o outro. Os dois são complementares e com objetivos distintos.

Um exemplo de Dockerfile seria

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
COPY . /app
RUN make /app
CMD python /app/app.py
```

Neste caso, é usada uma imagem base (ubuntu), são copiados arquivos, executa-se o comando make e define-se um comando inicial para o FUTURO container. Digo futuro, pois o comando poderá vir a ser executado quando a imagem gerada por este Dockerfile for usada na criação de um container.

Um exemplo de docker-compose seria

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

Neste caso são criados 2 serviços: uma aplicação (web) e um database (redis). Repare que a imagem foi definida para um deles e para o outro não. Isso é porque no caso do serviço "web" ainda não há uma imagem criada, será feito o build do Dockerfile presente no mesmo diretório onde o comando "docker-compose" for executado.

Answer (score 2):

> O docker-compose usa o DockerFile ou vice-versa?

**Dockerfile**: descreve os passos p/ criar uma imagem baseada na sua definição do que o container deve rodar.

**Docker Compose**: em vez de você ter que chamar `docker run comando_1 comando_2 comando_3 definir/montar_volume nome_do_container etc` , você define um arquivo `docker-compose.yml` com estas configurações e chama o docker compose atrás do comando `docker-compose up`

> Consigo fazer toda configuração só com um deles? Se sim, qual?

Fica a seu critério. Quando é algo simples, uso somente Dockerfile, se é mais complexo e depende de mais containers Docker Compose.