# Diferença entre Dockerfile e Docker-compose

Tags: docker

Estou com dúvidas acerca das imagens.

Eu entendi a parte que o Dockerfile cria a imagem e que o docker-compose gerencia as imagens que serão usadas naquela aplicação mas por que eu tenho que criar 1 imagens no dockerfile e baixar as outras pelo docker-compose como por exemplo:

Dockerfile

```
FROM node-alphine
```

docker-compose

```
services:
  pgsql
    image:postgres
```

Eu teria que criar a imagem do postgres no Dockerfile ?

Comment: geralmente quando se utiliza um dockerfile espera-se que esteja envolvido um conteudo local, na maior parte das vezes o próprio projeto, que você vai gerar a imagem, já no caso do postgres se você marcar ele lá no compose ele vai tentar baixar do dockerhub, pois é uma imagem que já existe

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Qual a diferença entre docker-compose e DockerFile?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/447482/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-docker-compose-e-dockerfile)

Answer (score 0):

Resumidamente, o **Docker** é a tecnologia de contêiner que permite que você coloque seus aplicativos em containers. Um container é uma unidade padrão de software que empacota o código e todas as suas dependências para que o aplicativo seja executado de forma rápida e confiável de um ambiente de computação para outro. O **Docker Compose** permite construir e executar vários contêineres no mesmo host.

> Eu teria que criar a imagem do postgres no Dockerfile ?

Não, você não precisa criar uma imagem do postgres no Dockerfile. Basta utilizar alguma imagem existente. Mas você precisa criar uma imagem para a sua aplicação. Por exemplo:

**.\docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    image: 'postgres:latest'
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  api:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./server
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./server:/app
    environment:
      - PGUSER=postgres
      - PGHOST=postgres
      - PGDATABASE=postgres
      - PGPASSWORD=postgres
      - PGPORT=5432
```

**.\server\Dockerfile.dev**

```
FROM node:14.14.0-alpine
WORKDIR "/app"
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```